# Run xscreensaver whenever the lid is closed

Tags: linux, power-management, ubuntu-10.10, xscreensaver

How can I run xscreensaver whenever the lid is closed? I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 with the awesome window manager.

Comment: and, Mr Schroedinger, how will you know if the screensaver runs when the lid is closed?

Comment: its actually running and not running at the same time until observed at which point it is no longer in super position and only in one state

Comment: @pavium: `ps` over SSH, duh. (Or, hide behind a corner and watch someone opening the lid and getting the Xscreensaver password prompt.)

Answer (score 0):

Using ubuntu 10.04, there is a file `/etc/acpi/sleep.sh`. That file contains, among others, the command `pm-suspend`, which is the suspend command. I assume that when you change that line, you can invoke the screensaver instead of suspending. Note that the file does some checks and bails out on some conditions which I do not grasp completely.

On your system the file might be named differently.

I did following search:

```
grep pm-suspend -r /etc/
```

---

Alternatively: you could replace the command `pm-suspend` with a script starting the screensaver. I really really do not recommend this. The package manager will not like this, and any other situations where pm-suspend is expected to work the way it does will break.